# Pycharm Not Opening README.md

Tags: pycharm, readme

I have a weird problem with a fresh install of pycharm community where I'm trying to open a README.md in the editor but it won't open. I'm not getting any errors or feedback at all it just won't show me the readme. I know I've opened them in the past but can't work out what's happening at the moment.

The pycharm markdown plugin is installed and I tried installing another one also but it hasn't changed the behaviour. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Mitchell

Comment: The same problem - nothing happens when clicking readme.md. My pycharm version is 2023.1 community edition

Comment: Me as well using 2023.2.1. However when I made a change to the file externally and viewed my git diffs it does appears? Also tried running as admin and checked *.md file association in Settings. Weird.

Comment: Currently, it opens normally for me. PyCharm 2023.1.3 (Community Edition). Build #PC-231.9161.41, built on June 23, 2023. Arch Linux.

Comment: I got mine to open by disabling the bundled Markdown Plugin via Setting/Plugins and closing PyCharm. When I relaunched, I was able to open the file and Pycharm asked me if I wanted to enable plugin. If I do, it doesn't open. I'm ignoring the extension for now. Seems the bundled md plugin isn't working. HTH

Comment: This has been fixed for me with  2023.3.2 (Community Edition)